# sum and binomial coefficient induction proof

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I bet the proof is simple but I have little experience with binomial coefficients and sums. I am curious about how you would solve this by induction:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^k {n\choose i} \leq n^k + 1$$

for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Where $n$ and $k$ are integers.

Comment: You could use Pascal identity and induction$$  {n+1\choose k+1 }= {n\choose k+1 }+{n\choose k }$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I assume that checking for the base case is done
- Also, let's assume it's true for $k \leftarrow k$
- Now we will show that the statement is true for $k \leftarrow k+1$
  $$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} {n\choose i} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} {n\choose i} + {n\choose {k+1}}\leq n^k+1+ {n\choose {k+1}}$$
  So it comes down to show that
  $$n^k+1+ {n\choose {k+1}} \le n^{k+1}+1$$
  Or equivalently,
  $${n \choose k+1} \leq n^{k+1}-n^k = n^k(n-1)$$
  Now using the fact that
  $${n \choose k+1} = \frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k)}{(k+1)!}$$
  it's quite easy to check that
  $$\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k)}{(k+1)!} \le n^k(n-1)$$
  is true.